# How to execute code when user closes form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want a msg box to appear if certain fields are empty on close.

```vb
Private Sub Close_Click()
    If IsNull(Me.startDate) Then
       MsgBox “You are in Phase 1”
    End If
End Sub
```

I want the pop up to appear when user clicks the exit x. I tried OnClose. Right now the code is attached to and works via a button.

I’d like the code to be executed when the user closes the form.

Edit New Code:

```vb
Private Sub Exit_Click ()
    If IsNull(Me.startDate) Or IsNull(Me.stepOneA) Or IsNull(Me.stepOneB) Then
        MsgBox “You are in Step I”
        DoCmd.Close
    ElseIf IsNull(Me.stepTwoA) or IsNull(Me.stepTwoB) or IsNull(stepTwoC)
        MsgBox “You are in Step II”
        DoCmd.Close
    Else
        DoCmd.Close
    EndIf
End Sub
```

Comment: I always disable X close and use button. You need `Else Me.Close`. What was code for OnClose event? "Didn't work" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens?

Comment: @June7 I updated my code, it works perfectly on my exit button. But like I said I don’t want a button, I want the pop up to appear when I click the x. My OnClose and CloseWindow code was the exact same except I removed the control name and change Click to either OnClose or CloseWindow and nothing happened.

Comment: Change how - by typeover? Did you make sure `[Event Procedure]` is in event property? Close event does not require DoCmd.Close. Didn't post OnClose event code. It's just another button click.

Comment: Actually the button is fine, so this works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *UnLoad* event for this:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)

    Cancel = IsNull(Me.startDate)

    If Cancel = True Then
       MsgBox "You are in Phase 1."
    End If

End Sub
```